# How to get the right http file length with qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to get the url "https://iso.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/qtproject/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.1.exe" file's length with Qt,

but QNetworkAccessManager request cannot get the Content-Length。 the content is

```
<html><head><script>document.cookie="addr=113.57.128.130";setTimeout("location.reload();", 2);</script></head><body>This page requires JavaScript. Please wait 2 seconds.
</body></html>
```

if I add the `cookie="addr=113.57.128.130"` to request manually, I can get the right things。 what should I do to get the file length?

Answer (score 2):

Try this example :

**widget.h**

```
public:
    void requestFileSize(const QString &url);
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_netmanager;
    QNetworkReply *m_reply;

public slots:
    void fileSize();
```

**widget.cpp**

```
void Widget::requestFileSize(const QString &url)
{
    QNetworkRequest req;
    m_netmanager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    req.setUrl(QUrl(url));
    m_reply = m_netmanager->get(req);
    connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(metaDataChanged()), this, SLOT(fileSize()));
}

void Widget::fileSize()
{
    qDebug() << "Content Length: " << m_reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toString();
    m_reply->deleteLater();
    m_netmanager->deleteLater();
}
```

Now call :

```
requestFileSize("https://as5.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/c6f1e63e310060e70574f1692c2322395584619-360p__37462.mp4");
```

Output in byte :

```
Content Length:  "12186677"
```

And its approximately `11.6 MB`

I test it with some `url`s but i dont know why with this `url` https://iso.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/qtproject/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.1.exe always return `0`.

Comment: I also try what you mention but it seems that you are using js to redirect, so if you do a get  you will get a message signaling that.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry i didn't exactly what you meant?

Comment: So it seems to me that when you make the request to the page it redirects to another page using javascript, so your method does not work, if you check the message of the get: *You failed to pass our validation.\nPlease use a normal browser or command line to download files.\nWe expect your ip is 113.57.128.130\nbut we got xxx\n*

Comment: @eyllanesc its a strict url, its has `.mp4` extension. i dont think its redirect....

Comment: I do not talk about your test url, but about the url of the asker: https://iso.mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/qtproject/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.1.exe

Comment: As I say your method works for regular cases, if I'm not trying to argue about the url of the asker

Comment: @eyllanesc oh, i got it

Comment: @eyllanesc why `QNetworkRequest` cant catch final url? when its redirect? this class should work fine without any contradiction.... is not it?

Comment: the norm is that the redirection is in the header, in this case it does not. On the other hand, QNetworkManager can not execute javascript, so it fails, I tried to download it with wget and it still fails.

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, with `wget` just its progressed till 183 byte

Comment: wget does not download the .exe but the html

Comment: @eyllanesc auto redirection support is just added to `Qt 5.6`. Check this out `QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html) i found this subject... is this can help? as a good answer?

Comment: I've already tried it and the problem is that qnetwork does not support js

Comment: @eyllanesc i thought my answer will be accept, or at least got an upvote.... but unfortunately not.....

Comment: hahaha, I had already implemented your solution and do not publish it because it does not solve the problem, do not expect it to be accepted because it does not solve the problem, they could give you some upvotes, you will have to wait. I was excited because I thought you had solved the problem, but in the end I was disappointed. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc not problem